# Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS, do not find external disk usb

Tags: usb, disk

I have a server HP ProLiant DL360e Gen8 with Ubuntu Server 18.04.2 LTS, the intention is to make a backup, to be saved on an external hard drive brand Toshiba 2TB, but it doesn't recognize it... disconnect the disk I run the commands `lsusb` and `sudo fdisk -l` do not change the results. The funny thing is that if I connect a USB keyboard, it works correctly, but even so it does not show any change in the results of the commands executed.

> lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0627:0001 Adomax Technology Co., Ltd
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

> sudo fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sda: 1.2 TiB, 1288490188800 bytes, 2516582400 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000631bf

Device     Boot  Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *      2048     499711     497664  243M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       501758 2516580351 2516078594  1.2T  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       501760 2516580351 2516078592  1.2T 8e Linux LVM


Disk /dev/mapper/webserver--vg-root: 1.2 TiB, 1279304663040 bytes, 2498641920 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/mapper/webserver--vg-swap_1: 8.3 GiB, 8925478912 bytes, 17432576 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

> dmesg | grep mount

```
[   16.916826] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   20.174290] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   25.236614] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   25.263170] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
```

> sudo lsblk

```
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                        8:0    0  1.2T  0 disk 
├─sda1                     8:1    0  243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                     8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5                     8:5    0  1.2T  0 part 
  ├─webserver--vg-root   253:0    0  1.2T  0 lvm  /
  └─webserver--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  8.3G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                       11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

> dmesg | grep -i usb`

```
[    0.220105] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.220128] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.220138] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.220188] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.078962] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.082441] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.085878] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.132221] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.135953] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
[    1.137140] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.138271] usb usb1: Product: UHCI Host Controller
[    1.139393] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.15.0-46-generic uhci_hcd
[    1.140618] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:01.2
[    1.141947] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.484024] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
[    1.679400] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0627, idProduct=0001
[    1.680594] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=5
[    1.681789] usb 1-1: Product: QEMU USB Tablet
[    1.682955] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: QEMU
[    1.684125] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 42
[    1.702388] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.703636] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.707748] input: QEMU QEMU USB Tablet as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:0627:0001.0001/input/input5
[    1.710842] hid-generic 0003:0627:0001.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v0.01 Mouse [QEMU QEMU USB Tablet] on usb-0000:00:01.2-1/input0`
```

Comment: try using `lsblk`

Comment: try to view log, by typing  dmesg  in terminal. there may be device errro while connecting

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help:dmesg | grep mount
[   16.916826] EXT4-fs (dm-0): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   20.174290] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   25.236614] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   25.263170] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)

Comment: sudo lsblk
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                        8:0    0  1.2T  0 disk 
├─sda1                     8:1    0  243M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                     8:2    0    1K  0 part 
└─sda5                     8:5    0  1.2T  0 part 
  ├─webserver--vg-root   253:0    0  1.2T  0 lvm  /
  └─webserver--vg-swap_1 253:1    0  8.3G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sr0                       11:0    1 1024M  0 rom

Comment: 1. Did it ever work before? 2. Kernel version? 3. `dmesg | grep -i usb`

Comment: Hi, thanks for help, the owner told me, that a long time ago the server recognized it, although I'm not sure about it, I already tested the disk on another machine and recognized it perfectly. added the results dmesg | grep -i usb

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. But it looks like you've got a 1.2TB HDD using dos/mbr partition tables. It should be GPT. It also looks like it may be using ext2 filesystem, s/b ext4. Is the external HDD a USB3 device, plugged into a USB3 port?

Comment: Hi, yes is a external disk Toshiba 2tb, but i can't see it. Thanks for your ask

Answer (score 0):

server had usb protection block from BIOS, thanks a lot everybody!